# Format attributes for XML in Pretty format in java

Tags: java, xml, dom, sax

I am trying to format XML string to pretty. I want all the attributes to be printed in single line.
XML input:

```
<root><feeds attribute1="a" attribute2="b" attribute3="c" attribute4="d" attribute5="e" attribute6="f"> <id>2140</id><title>gj</title><description>ghj</description>
<msg/>
```

Expected output:

```
<root>
<feeds attribute1="a" attribute2="b" attribute3="c" attribute4="d" attribute5="e" attribute6="f">
    <id>2140</id>
    <title>gj</title>
    <description>ghj</description>
    <msg/>
</feeds>
```

Actual Output:

```
<root>
<feeds attribute1="a" attribute2="b" attribute3="c" attribute4="d"
    attribute5="e" attribute6="f">
    <id>2140</id>
    <title>gj</title>
    <description>ghj</description>
    <msg/>
</feeds>
```

Here is my code to format xml. I have also tried SAX parser. I don't want to use DOM4J.

```
public static String formatXml(String xml) {
  DOMImplementationRegistry registry = DOMImplementationRegistry.newInstance();
  DOMImplementationLS impl = (DOMImplementationLS) registry.getDOMImplementation("LS");
  LSSerializer writer = impl.createLSSerializer();
  writer.getDomConfig().setParameter("format-pretty-print", Boolean.TRUE);
  writer.getDomConfig().setParameter("xml-declaration", false);
  writer.getDomConfig().setParameter("well-formed", true);

  LSOutput output = impl.createLSOutput();
  ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  output.setByteStream(out);

  DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
  DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
  InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(xml));

  writer.write(db.parse(is), output);
  return  new String(out.toByteArray());
}
```

Is there any way to keep attributes in one line with SAX or DOM parser? I am not looking for any additional library. I am looking for solution with java library only.

Comment: What `format-pretty-print` really is depends on the serializer implementation. In this case it "could" be related to the line width of the output but there's really an issue since the number of attributes could be any. You should perhaps write a custom formatter or use xslt.

Comment: There should be a property to define number of characters in single element, or a flag to disable warp. Are you aware of anything? I check this, but no luck. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/DOMConfiguration.html

Comment: I took a look at source code yesterday but didn't find the place where format is implemented.

Comment: I found the place where parsing is done: `com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(boolean)` and probably this is the class for formatting: `com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl`.

Answer (score 1):

A SAX or DOM parser will read your input string and allow your application to understand what was passed in. At some point in time your application then writes out that data, and that is the moment where you decide to insert additional whitespace (like linefeeds and tab characters) to pretty-print the document.

If you really want to use SAX and make the parser efficient the best you could do is write the document while it is being parsed. So you would implement the ContentHandler interface (https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.xml/org/xml/sax/ContentHandler.html) such that it directly writes out the data while adding linefeeds where you feel they belong to.

Check this tutorial to see how the ContentHandler can then be applied in a SAX parser: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/sax/parsing.html

Comment: I don't want to create customer parser just for a small feature, but there should be flag to disable this behavior or line width variable. Are you aware about anything?

Comment: I am not aware of explicit line width features. But on the other hand filling in one interface is a lot less work than actually creating a parser.